# How to compact two 4-bit integers into an 8-bit integer in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an array of integers in the range [-8, 7] and I want to write them in a binary file. Since 4 bits are enough to represent these numbers, I want to compact every two elements in one 8-bit integer so that I will get a smaller file. This is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int8_t a1{-1}, a2{1};
    uint8_t a1_4bit = (((uint8_t)a1 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + (uint8_t)a1 & 0b00000111;
    uint8_t a2_4bit = (((uint8_t)a2 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + (uint8_t)a2 & 0b00000111;
    uint8_t compact_a = (a1_4bit << 4) + a2_4bit;

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is I'm taking the sign bit and the three LSB bits and putting them next to each other. But when I try to extract the the original integers from `compact_a` I get `7` and `1` instead of `-1` and `1`. The code I use for extracting original numbers is:

```cpp
    uint8_t a_re = compact_a/16 ;
    uint8_t a_im = compact_a%16 ;

    a_re = a_re << 4 ;
    a_im = a_im << 4 ;


    int8_t a_re2 = *(int8_t *) &a_re ;
    int8_t a_im2 = *(int8_t *) &a_im ;

    a_re2 = a_re2 >> 4 ;
    a_im2 = a_im2 >> 4 ;
```

I'm not sure if the first code snippet is misleading or useful, so whether an update to my code or a completely different method is appreciated.

Comment: You don’t need to go get the sign bit separately: all bits above the last “real” bit have the same value in 2’s complement (which you are of course already assuming).

Comment: +8 and save 4 bits. Read 4 bits and -8. `uint8_t compact_a = ((a1_4bit + 8) << 4) + (a2_4bit + 8);`

Comment: @273K I think you mean `uint8_t compact_a = ((a1 + 8) << 4) + (a2 + 8);` right? Cause otherwise it wouldn't have much benefit.

Comment: yes, expanded wrongly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is operator precedence. If you change

```
uint8_t a1_4bit = (((uint8_t)a1 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + (uint8_t)a1 & 0b00000111;
uint8_t a2_4bit = (((uint8_t)a2 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + (uint8_t)a2 & 0b00000111;
```

to be

```
uint8_t a1_4bit = (((uint8_t)a1 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + ((uint8_t)a1 & 0b00000111);
uint8_t a2_4bit = (((uint8_t)a2 & 0b10000000) >> 4) + ((uint8_t)a2 & 0b00000111);
```

(note the extra brackets on the right-hand parts), it will work as expected.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8fTn89YrP)

Note that since you are doing bitwise operations, use | instead of + as a general rule, to avoid unexpected sign issues in some later project.

Comment: OP is likely to run into the exact same bug when reading the file, converting each character read from it into2. It would perhaps be useful to demonstrate how to write that operation too.

Answer (score 1):

The mask `0b00000111` seems wrong. You need four bits, i.e. mask with `0b1111`. I'm not entirely sure if I understand your approach though.

The basic idea is that an integer in range `[-8, 7]` can be represented using a 4-bit two's complement integer. Since C++20, signed integers are guaranteed to be represented with two's complement, which means that:

- narrowing wider signed integers (like `int`) is done by bit-masking the least 4 bits
- widening to a wider signed integer (like `int`) is done by sign-extension

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

std::uint8_t pack(int lo, int hi) {
    return (lo & 0b1111) << 0
         | (hi & 0b1111) << 4;
}

int sx4(int x) {
    // This assumes that int is 32-bit.
    // Making this nice and portable is an exercise for the reader.
    return x << 28 >> 28;
}

std::pair<int, int> unpack(std::uint8_t data) {
    return { sx4((data >> 0) & 0b1111), sx4((data >> 4) & 0b1111) };
}

int main() {
    std::uint8_t packed = pack(-8, 7);
    auto [lo, hi] = unpack(packed);
    std::cout << lo << ' ' << hi << '\n';
}
```

This prints

```
-8
7
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dWMhda6Kx)*

Pay special attention to the `sx4` function, which sign-extends a 4-bit two's complement signed integer to form a 32-bit two's complement signed integer. `sx4` basically maps `8` onto `-8`, `9` onto `-7`, ... `15` onto `-1`.

Comment: *"The mask 0b00000111 seems wrong."* In fact OP takes `0b1000'0111` as mask (sign/2-complement, and "regular" bits). OP didn't notice that all higher bits (from `0b1111'1000`) would be the same.

Comment: Thanks. About the mask, I was trying to get the sign bit separately. I think the mask `0b1111` works because of the 2's complement representation and the range of numbers, the fourth bit will be equal to the sign bit, right?

Comment: Also, about this statement: "Since C++20, signed integers are guaranteed to be represented with two's complement", what was the case before C++20?

Comment: @nasy a bunch of operations were already defined to work as if integers were two's complement, but some weren't, and the requirements on the representation technically allowed sign+magnitude et al. See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html for more

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to store any pair of integers between -8 and 7 in a single byte.  It does rely on some implementation-defined behavior when extracting the numbers though: specifically it assumes your compiler does an arithmetic right shift when you use `>>` on a negative number (i.e. it preserves the sign).

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int8_t a1 = -4;
  int8_t a2 = -5;

  // Store in compact form:
  uint8_t compact = ((a1 & 0xF) << 4) | (a2 & 0xF);

  // Extract and restore sign:
  int8_t b1 = (int8_t)compact >> 4;
  int8_t b2 = (int8_t)(compact << 4) >> 4;

  printf("a1 = %d, a2 = %d\n", a1, a2);
  printf("compact = 0x%x\n", compact);
  printf("b1 = %d, b2 = %d\n", b1, b2);
}
```